# Locking "visible" conditionally formatted cells within a named range

Tags: vba, excel

**Overview**

I'm trying to lock cells within a named range that have ***visible*** conditional formatting. The 3 linked images below will illustrate my constraints:

[Name range: *table* (cells C1:E6)  is set to be conditionally formatted with a blue fill color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMYGn.png)

[This is the conditional format fill color (color index #: 37) being used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8cA6.png)

[The row will change to the blue fill if criteria in column A is met, i.e. if the corresponding row in column A has the letter "f" as input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v68Qc.png)

In summary, I'm trying to lock the rows with the ***visible*** blue fill within the named range as well as the *rest* of the worksheet. And, I only want to edit cells within the named range that don't have the *visible* blue fill conditional format.

**My Solution (so far)...**

This macro creates the named range mentioned above and used in LockCells() macro (which is below this code snippet):

```
Sub NameRange()
'Create named range

Dim rng As Range
Dim range_name As String
Dim cells As String
Dim wkst As String

'Target worksheet
wkst = "Sheet1"

'Range of cells
range_name = "table"
cells = "C1:E6"

'Creates named range
Set rng = Worksheets(wkst).Range(cells)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=range_name, RefersTo:=rng

End Sub
```

This macro loops through cells in named range (*table*) and *attempts* to lock the ***visible*** blue conditional formatted rows in named range:

```
Sub LockCells()
'Loop through cells in a given named range
'and lock cells based on blue fill color

Dim cell As Range
Dim color_index As Integer

'Target fill color
color_index = 37

'Target worksheet to protect
wkst = "Sheet1"

'Loop through cells in named range
For Each cell In Range("table")
    Dim color As Long
    color = cell.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex

    If (color = color_index) Then
      cell.Locked = False
    Else
      cell.Locked = True
    End If
Next

Sets protection for worksheet
Worksheets(wkst).Protect

End Sub
```

**Problem**

I'm stuck because instead of locking the ***visible*** blue filled cells, and keeping the other cells unlocked for editing, in the named range *table* it locks all of cells. Mind you, I do want the rest of the worksheet outside of the named range to be locked and protected. I know it's because the conditional format is applied to the named range and evaluating as true. Which is why it locks all cells in named range. My question about solving this issue is below.

**Question**

Is there state (or visibility) property for conditionally formatted cells?

I was thinking if there is such a property, I could use it in the *if* statement of my LockCells() macro. E.g. *If (color = color_index) & [Conditional Format Visible] Then*...

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Are you locking if the conditional formatting formula /condition for the cell evaluated to true? That might be a route in.

Comment: This might be of interest http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example to work from. I have one format condition which happens to be Cell Value = 2 so I can refer to that rule via `.FormatConditions(1)` And as the rule is "=" I can use the comparison I have. You would want to adapt to the formula you are using.

**Code:**

```
Sub test()

    Dim curr As Range

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False

    For Each curr In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:E6")

        With curr.FormatConditions(1)

            If curr.Value = Evaluate(.Formula1) Then curr.Locked = True

        End With

    Next curr

    For Each curr In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:E6")

        Debug.Print curr.Address & " locked = " & curr.Locked

    Next curr

End Sub
```

**Conditional format rule:**

[image: Rule]

**Sheet:**

[image: Formatting in sheet]

**Reference:**

http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)